# compute $\lim_{{{x}\to\infty}}{5}{x}-\lim_{{{y}\to{0}^{+}}}\frac{{5}}{{y}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

For $\lim_{{{x}\to\infty}}{5}{x}$, let ${x}=\frac{{1}}{{t}}$,

thus $\lim_{{{x}\to\infty}}{5}{x}=\lim_{{{t}\to{0}^{+}}}\frac{{5}}{{t}}$,

obviously, $\lim_{{{t}\to{0}^{+}}}\frac{{5}}{{t}}=\lim_{{{y}\to{0}^{+}}}\frac{{5}}{{y}}$,

so $\lim_{{{x}\to\infty}}{5}{x}-\lim_{{{y}\to{0}^{+}}}\frac{{5}}{{y}}=\lim_{{{t}\to{0}^{+}}}\frac{{5}}{{t}}-\lim_{{{y}\to{0}^{+}}}\frac{{5}}{{y}}={0}$.

Is the computing process right ?

Comment: Both limits evaluate to "infinity", and the operation of subtracting infinities is ill-defined on $ \mathbb R^* $ (Edited $ \mathbb R $ to $ \mathbb R^* $, the two-point closure of $ \mathbb R $).

Comment: By the way, $\lim_{y \to 0} 5/y$ does not exist...

Comment: @Siminore You're right. I hastily assumed he meant $ 0^+ $ the same way one writes $ \infty $ to mean $ +\infty $, but my comment is definitely misleading.

Comment: @derpy  
I updated the post

Comment: @Siminore  I updated the post

Answer (score 4):

One of the limits does not exist and the other is "equal" to $\infty$, so all in all, there can be no answer to your question, and the answer most certainly is not $0$.

Also, it is not true that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} 5x = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac 5t$$
because the left side has a limit of $\infty$ and the right one does not.

After the edit, both limits are now equal to $\infty$, but that still means that their difference does not exist.

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Now both limits diverge to $+\infty$, so you cannot get a conclusion by subtracting them.